# Textarea located in ascx user control, getting value of ite with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, ascx

I have an asp.net main page which loads an ascx control inside it.

On the main page I have a textarea element declared as

```
<asp:TextBox ID="description" runat="server" Rows="8" Columns="35" TextMode="MultiLine" class="smth" title="A Title"></asp:TextBox>
```

which renders as

```
<textarea name="description" rows="8" cols="35" id="description" class="smth" title="A Title"></textarea>
```

On the ascx control I have declared a similar textbox as

```
<textarea id="descriptionMap" rows="5" cols="25" class="smth" title="A Title"></textarea>
```

which renders the same.

On the main page I can access the contents of first textbox (contained on main page) with

```
$('#' + <%=description.ClientID %>).val()
```

But I am unable to access the contents of textbox contained on ascx control with

```
$('#descriptionMap').val()
```

However, if I declare the textbox in ascx file as

```
<textarea id="descriptionMap">some static content</textbox>
```

I can access this, but if I'm writing something to the textbox myself, nothing happens. This is driving me nuts. Any suggestions? I am using IE 8, could that be the problem?

Edit. A simplified example. This is how the ascx control renders:

```
<textarea id="descriptionMap" rows="5" cols="25" class="smth" title="A Title"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="sendMap" value="Send" onclick="sendTest();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendTest() {
    alert(document.getElementById('descriptionMap').value);
}</script>
```

The alert dialog shows up empty. The problem must be related to using ascx controls somehow.

Comment: Are you sure that the textarea id is being rendered as "descriptionMap"?

Comment: Yes. That is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear if you are using a server control `<asp:TextBox runat="server"...` or directly creating the html element `<textarea id="descriptionMap"...` inside your ascx page.

If you are using the first option (creating a server side control inside the ascx), then the final ID of the element would be based on the ID of the user control itself.

For example, if you have added your user control in the main page as

```
<uc:MyTag runat="server" Id="MyControl01" />
```

Then the final ID of the textarea inside the user control would be **`MyControl01_descriptionMap`** and you will need to access it using **`$('#MyControl01_descriptionMap')`** (If you are using the default ClientIDMode in .NET framework 4 and above).

But if you are directly creating a html element inside your ascx file then you need to make sure that your id is unquie and you can use the same id to access the control.

Comment: I am creating the html element directly. And I am sure that the id is unique. As I stated in original post, if i create static content to the textarea directly in ascx file, I have no problem getting it. But it does not work for user-typed content.

I am registering the user control as `<%@ Reference Control="~/MapPopUp.ascx" %>` and then load it in codebehind like

`Dim mapPopUp As Control = LoadControl("~/MapPopUp.ascx")
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(mapPopUp)`. Is this a right way to load the user control?

Comment: Sure that is one way of doing it, another straight forward way of accomplishing the same is as per the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Can you paste the final source that is coming to the browser and update your question? thanks

Comment: In your edited sample you have shown the code as `alert(document.getElementById('descriptionMap').value)` the selector is missing the `#` sign. You need to have it as `alert(document.getElementById('#descriptionMap').value)`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('#' + '<%= description.ClientID %>').val()
```

or

```
$('#<%= description.ClientID %>').val()
```